# Imported but unused

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-requests, web-scrapping

Porque no me deja usar las librerías bs4, requests y xmlx de python en VSC?? recién estoy empezando a estudiar WebScraping

En cada parte de las librerías me sale lo siguiente

> Imported but unused

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu archivo no estás usando nada que contenga esa librería. Básicamente te dice que lo llamaste, pero aún no lo utilizas. Cuando empieces a desarrollar el código y a usar lo que trae esas librerías, te irán desapareciendo. Creo hay maneras igual para hacer que desaparezcan esas advertencias.

Comment: No te dice en ningún momento que no puedas usarlos, son solo warnings (advertencias) del linter, " x  importado pero no  usado", te avisa de que has importado algo (un modulo en este caso) que no usas en el código (lo cual es innecesario e ineficiente, pero en tu caso es que aun no has escrito nada de código...). En el momento que uses alguna función, clase, etc de ese import el warning desaparecerá.